# Changing Administrator of WhatsApp group due to non-working mobile and migration to another country

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, device-migration

My friend is an Administrator of our group on WhatsApp. He migrated from Singapore to US and as a result, his phone is not working. I would like to take the Administrator privileges for adding him back to the group using US phone number. Can you please share suggestions for solving this issue?

Thanks,
Aniruddh

Answer (score 1):

No need to remove all users. Just add the person who want to become the admin, then leave or exit the group. The last person you added will automatically become the group admin.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend need to change the whatsapp number first.

Whatsapp -> Settings-> Account-> Change Number... and follow instructions.

Next Step add the one who needs to be the admin to the group(here you)(skip this as you are already in the group).

Remove all others except you and the present admin(your friend) from the group.

Now your friend (present admin) needs to 'Delete and exit ' the group. Now the one who's left will become admin.

Add all your friends back to group. 
Voila :-)

<sup>[Source](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2535153)</sup>

Comment: I think this will help:-)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Answer edited.! Thanks for the information. @bmdixon

Comment: Actually to reach the OP's stated goal of having his friend be a member with his new USA number, the friend only needs to follow  the first step of this answer. Once he's changed his account number, all should be well.